# How do you call a python script from bin when you keep getting permission errors

Tags: python

I have my python scripts in `/usr/bin` and I'm trying to call them from `/usr/otherfolder` my issue is that even after I call `chmod 755 file.py` and `chmod +x file.py` I still get the error message `/usr/bin/file.py: Permission Denied.`
The first line of my python file is

```
#!/usr/bin/ python
```

and the call that gives me this error is just

```
file.py
```

I'm trying to get rid of the path to the file as well as the word python so someone who takes this script can use it after just placing it in their bin

My question is how do you get around the permission error even after making this file an executable?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/ python` ==> `#!/usr/bin/python` maybe

Comment: Remove the space from your shebang line

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. Now the command can't be found

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python`  Also, tell us the result of `which python`.

Comment: @mpez0 /usr/bin/python

Comment: @mpez0 should I make an /env directory that holds the scripts?

Comment: @PeterTWalker No, /usr/bin/env is an executable that sets up the environment for your python invocation.

Comment: /usr/bin/env: No such file or directory @mpez0

Comment: @PeterTWalker On my CentOS box, env in in the coreutils package. Not sure for your distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your script file's path to your PATH variable.

1. Create a folder called "bin" in your home directory (or in anywhere with whatever you want to name it)
2. Move your file to this folder (be ensure that you have required permission for this folder an also execute permission for this file)
3. Open the "~/.bashrc" file and add this line to the end of the file:

```sh
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Note: For this case I assumed that you create a folder called "bin" in your home directory, or else you should replace the "~/bin" part of the line according to  your own folder path.

4. Save it and execute following command:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

And now, you are done.

I hope, it will work.

Comment: I'm still getting permission denied

Comment: Have you changed the file permissions according as executable by the user with `chmod 744 file.extension` after you added it to path?

Comment: I tried chmod 744 and I still get /usr/bin/env: No such file or directory and when I change my first line of python to #!/usr/bin python I still get permission denied

Comment: Are you sure about the permissions of `/usr/bin folder`? You may not have the right privileges for that folder or `/usr` folder